# In Cygwin, why does echo $PATH work, but $PATH fail?

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, cygwin, path

As seen here, doing `echo $PATH` gives me my full PATH, but doing simply `$PATH` gives an incomplete version that looks like it hasn't been escaped properly somewhere:

[image]

Yet when I look into my configuration files, the only relevant lines for the PATH seem to be:

```
PATH=$PATH
```

...in `.bashrc`, and...

```
export PATH=usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH
export PATH=/sbin:$PATH
export PATH=/cygdrive/b/users/me/desktop:$PATH
```

...in `.bash_profile`. Both seem correctly formatted to me, so I'm unsure what's going on here. Can anyone else shed some light on it?

Comment: Generally, the first thing on the command line should be a *command* name (well, or an assignment). `$PATH` is a variable... that doesn't contain a valid command name. So running `$PATH` as a command is not really expected to do anything particularly sane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I assume you deleted your username from between `users/` and `/desktop`. It now looks like few spaces, but in fact there is no space there.)

When you invoke sole `$PATH`, the first space in it separates what `bash` interprets as a command from its first argument. `No such file or directory` refers to the "command".

The first space is in `Program Files`, therefore the "command" ends with `Program`. It fails because there's no such file.

Answer (score 2):

PATH is a variable (that is used by the shell to try and locate programs by looking in each of it's directories.)

When you run echo $PATH you are showing the contents if it.

When you run $PATH you are attempting to run the command included in the variable. As this is a list of directories, it's not a valid command do it produces the error.